# How to use Flow to type a generic reselect selector?

Tags: javascript, lodash, flowtype, reselect

I have two types of similar, but distinct, structures:

```
type A = { foo: string, bar: string, specialA: string };
type B = { foo: string, bar: string, specialB: string };
```

I am using `reselect` to create selectors, using the types from `flow-typed` [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/reselect_v3.x.x/flow_v0.47.x-). The only modification I made was to export the OutputSelector type.

I have three files with the following purposes:

`generic.js`: Exports generic selectors using this pattern:

```
export const someSelector = selector => createSelector(selector, ...)
```

`a.js`: Exports selectors specific to `type A` like this:

```
import { someSelector } from './generic.js';

const aSelector = state => state.a;

export selector = someSelector(aSelector);
```

`b.js`: Same as `a.js` but for `type B`

So the idea is that I pass a specific selector to the generic selector, that will select the appropriate type. I am having trouble making it so that the type information is preserved when using the specific selector somewhere. So some file only cares about `type A` so it imports a selector from `a.js`, but Flow complains that the returned objects can have props from either `A` or `B`. Since it's very difficult to track down exactly where this is all going wrong, I copy-pasted the selectors into `a.js` and `b.js` and made sure they work when there's no generics involved. Then I moved one selector into `generic.js` to try and narrow down the problem. I have this:

```
type Base = { foo: string, bar: string };
type SpecificSelector<T> = OutputSelector<State, mixed, T>;
export const selector = <T: Base, A: $ReadOnlyArray<T>, R: { [string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T> }>(specificSelector: SpecificSelector<A>) =>
  createSelector(
    specificSelector,
    (arr: A): R => groupBy(arr, (o: T): mixed => finding.foo),
  );
```

The definition of `lodash`'s `groupBy`:

```
groupBy<V, T>(
  array: $ReadOnlyArray<T>,
  iteratee?: ?ValueOnlyIteratee<T>,
): { [key: V]: $ReadOnlyArray<T> };
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ apps/acheron/src/selectors/util/generic.js:70:23

Cannot return groupBy(...) because object type [1] is incompatible with R [2].

     apps/acheron/src/selectors/util/generic.js
      67│ export const selector = <T: Base, A: $ReadOnlyArray<T>, R: { [string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T> }>(specificSelector: SpecificSelector<A>) => createSelector(
      68│   specificSelector,
      69│
 [2]  70│   (arr: A): R => groupBy(arr, (o: T): mixed => o.foo),
      71│ );
      72│

     flow-typed/npm/lodash_v4.x.x.js
 [1] 708│     ): { [key: V]: $ReadOnlyArray<T> };
```

I don't understand why they are incompatible. If I remove the generic param `R` and just return the value returned by `groupBy`, I have another problem:

```
export const selector1 = <T: Base, A: $ReadOnlyArray<T>>(specificSelector: SpecificSelector<A>) => createSelector(
  specificSelector,

  (arr: A): {[string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>} => groupBy(arr, (o: T): mixed => o.foo),
);

export const selector2 = <T: Base, A: $ReadOnlyArray<T>>(specificSelector: SpecificSelector<A>) => createSelector(
  [selector1(specificSelector),
  (state: State, props: mixed): ?string => props && props.match && props.match.params && typeof props.match.params.appId === 'string' ? props.match.params.appId : null],

  (arr: {[string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>}, appId: ?string): ?$ReadOnlyArray<T> =>
    arr && appId && arr[appId]
      ? arr[appId]
      : null,
);
```

The new error:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ apps/acheron/src/selectors/util/generic.js:74:4

Cannot call createSelector with array literal bound to selectors because:
 • Base [1] is incompatible with T [2] in array element of the indexer property of the return value of index 0.
 • T [1] is incompatible with Base [2] in array element of the indexer property of the return value of index 0.

 [1] 70│   (arr: A): {[string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>} => groupBy(arr, (o: T): mixed => o.foo),
     71│ );
     72│
     73│ export const selector2 = <T: Base, A: $ReadOnlyArray<T>>(specificSelector: SpecificSelector<A>) => createSelector(
     74│   [selector1(specificSelector),
     75│   (state: State, props: mixed): ?string => props && props.match && props.match.params && typeof props.match.params.appId === 'string' ? props.match.params.appId : null],
     76│
 [2] 77│   (arr: {[string]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>}, appId: ?string): ?$ReadOnlyArray<T> =>
     78│     arr && appId && arr[appId]
```

I understand this to read that since the object returned by lodash is no longer a generic parameter, type information is being lost, and Flow cannot ensure that the same keys are contained in both objects?